# Python: Why does my code have incorrect output

Tags: python, outliers

What is wrong with this? I am trying to find the quartiles of the numbers before and after the median. The output however is incorrect.

```
from statistics import median
this_list = [5, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 13, 450, 20]
outliers = []
def find_outlier(integers):
  ordered = sorted(integers)
  integers = ordered
  the_median =  median(integers)
  print(integers)
  q1 = median(integers[:the_median]) #outputs 5
  q3 = median(integers[the_median:])
  print(q1, q3)
  iqr = q3 - q1
  get_outlier = 1.5 * iqr
  low_outlier = q1 - get_outlier
  high_outlier = q3 + get_outlier
  for number in integers:
    if number < low_outlier or number > high_outlier 
      outliers.append(number)
  print('Your outliers are:' + str(outliers))
find_outlier(this_list)
```

Comment: `median()` returns the median value, not its index.

Comment: So `integers[:the_median]` doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`the_median` is the median value, not its index, so `integers[:the_median]` doesn't return the sub-list before the median. You can use a generator for this:

```
q1 = median(x for x in integers if x < the_median)
q3 = median(x for x in integers if x > the_median)
```

Note that it would not be correct to use `median_index = integers.index(the_median)`. If there are an even number of values in the original list, the median won't be one of the values, it will be the mean of the two values in the middle. So `index()` won't find the median in the list.

Because this is scanning the entire list, there's not really any point to sorting the list at the beginning of the function.